# Trying to create PostGIS database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, spatial, postgis

I am trying to create a spatially enabled PostGIS database by following the [PostGIS documentation](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch02.html#id2648455).

In the short version, i executed,

```
createdb yourdatabase
createlang plpgsql yourdatabase
```

But I did not execute the last three commands,

```
psql -d yourdatabase -f postgis.sql
psql -d yourdatabase -f postgis_comments.sql
psql -d yourdatabase -f spatial_ref_sys.sql
```

Is my database still spatially enabled? If not, then can you tell me where these .sql files are located so I can execute those last commands, since I am getting the following error,

```
postgis.sql: No such file or directory
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install PostGIS, GEOS, Proj and maybe other components first. If you install PostGIS successfully, the `postgis.sql`, `postgis_comments.sql`, `spatial_ref_sys.sql` will locate the `$PGHOME/share/contrib` directory.

Answer (score 1):

You must install the PostGIS functions, data types, etc. before you can use PostGIS. This can be found in these three SQL-files. Set the correct path to the files and execute them in PostgreSQL by using psql.

Answer (score 0):

I found the geodjango documentation really good.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/install/postgis/
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/

They have given step by step explanation on installing postgis and dependencies. You can consult the postgis documentation or other sources when instructions are django specific.

Comment: Thanks, but you've basically added a link-only answer which we don't like here because they break over time. Please add stand-alone answers, though supporting links are fine.

Comment: @Colin'tHart I totally agree with you. I considered to post entire content, but posted the links because size of content was too large and it belongs to django, so chances are thin that this content will be removed. Will improve the answer. But right now, detailed answer has more than 2 links I need more than 10 repo points for that.